# advice on paired results from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of data with two columns, user_id and preference_id. I'm struggling to figure out how to return pairs of user_ids that share a preference_id, and the count of any paired preferences.

I recognise this will be a subquery question, to first find a user_id with preference_id and then (in the subquery) check the database again for a new user_id with the same preference_id (and who isn't the first user). I can't figure out though how to construct the query.

Does it seem logical my subquery should be in the select section, since I want to return two different user_ids?

--- EDIT:

An example of the table is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `people_preferences`;
CREATE TABLE `people_preferences`
(
  `personid` int(11),
  `preferenceid` int(11)
);


INSERT INTO `people_preferences` VALUES (1,10),(1,24),(1,38),(2,1),(2,10),(2,38),(3,5),(3,38);
```

I'm believe I need something along the lines of:

```
select people_preferences.personid,
(select people_preferences.personid where....)
from people_preferences
where people_preferences.personid <> people_preferences.personid;
```

But clearly this isn't going to work as that final statement won't do anything sensible.

Comment: Would be great if you can share some data, sample inut and expected output.

Comment: Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: apologies, I've included an example of what I mean in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want pairs of users and a count.  If so:

```
select pp1.personid, pp2.personid,
       count(*) as num_preferences_in_common
from people_preferences pp1 join
     people_preferences pp2
     on pp1.preferenceid = pp2.preferenceid and
        pp1.personid < pp2.personid  -- only need pairs of people in one direction
group by pp1.personid, pp2.personid
order by num_preferences_in_common;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's new to me, I've never seen 'on' before.